# Import Bootstrap template in maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following problem: 
I am trying to add a complete bootstrap template to my maven project.
I add the following dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And then I add all files of the template to my folder resources/templates, because I am using thymeleaf.
So the structure of attributes is shown only, but bootstrap design is missing.

Can you help me ? :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it: (I am using Thymeleaf, but this should probably be easy to do even without)

1. Open the official bootstrap repo: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/
2. Go to Bootstrap CDN and copy the link given in the `href` attribute: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
3. Open the link in a new tab and copy its contents to your project (preferably in a file under resources/static):
   [image: like this]
4. Then, include this file using the link tag in your html files (In my case, `th:href`): `<link th:href="@{/CSS/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">`